# class's output in C#, how to do

Tags: c#

Here is my problem:
I want to output a value from a class when I call to its instance.
For example, I have a class like this:

```
class Car
{
    public string name = null;
    public int id;
    public int horsepower;
    public Car(int ID, string Name, int HorsePower)
    {
        this.id = ID;
        this.name = Name;
        this.horsepower = HorsePower;
    }
}
```

I want the output will be `"aventador lp700-4"` when I have a program like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Car car = new Car(1, "aventador lp700-4", 700);


        ////////////// I want the output will be "aventador lp700-4" /////////////////////
        Console.WriteLine(car);
        ///////////////////////////////

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

I find some dll library could do that, but I don't know how to to.

Comment: side note: at the moment you have "public fields" on the type - it is almost always preferable to use properties; for example: `public string Name {get;set;}` - they work very similarly, but make things far more flexible later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine(object)` wants to get a `string` for the object passed in; there are a few different ways it can do that, but the *default* (in the absence of you telling it something more specific) is that it is just going to call `.ToString()` on the argument. So: you need to `override` the `ToString()` method on `Car`, to tell it what you want to use to represent that type as a `string`:

```
class Car
{
    // ... your existing code
    public override string ToString() { return name; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the ToString method in your car class

```
public override string ToString(){
    return name;
}
```